# How to save list with OnClick event in python to add them in a single list and get intersection

Tags: python, list, append, intersection, set-intersection

EDITED: 
I want to find intersection of multiple list in python. So  first i will add  them to make a single list(list of lists), after that i am using  intersection function.
Let me explain what is happening here: 
First button click- you will a list from database table [1, 6, 7, 8]

Now i have to add this in a blank list.So as the first button is clicked it should give you the same list [[1, 6, 7, 8]] because there is a only one list to add.

and i am getting [[1, 6, 7, 8]]

second button click- got a list from database [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Now second button is clicked so i should get [[1, 6, 7, 8],[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]]

but what i am getting is [[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]]

Third button click- got a list [2, 4, 7, 8]

after clicking third button [[1, 6, 7, 8],[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8],[2, 4, 7, 8]]

but i am getting  [[2, 4, 7, 8]]

And so on depending on the number of buttons selected by user,which we don't how many buttons he can select.

Output after applying intersection function [7,8]

So finally I can have n number of lists, and i have add them and get listoflists.When i run this below code it gives me the output as mentioned above.I have written complete code so that you get an idea about my database.But my problem is related to the append and intersection inside the On Click event

```
    self.conn = sqlite3.connect('RAMAN.db')       
    for row_id in range(1,11):
       for col_id in range(1,19):
         print row_id,col_id
         cursor= self.conn.execute("SELECT * FROM ELEMENT where ROW_NO==%d AND COLUMN_NO==%d"%(row_id,col_id))
         if(cursor==None):
            gs.Add(wx.StaticText(p,-1,''))
         else:
            elements = cursor.fetchall()
            if(elements==None or len(elements)==0):
               gs.Add(wx.StaticText(p,-1,''))
            else:
               print elements[0]
               btn = wx.Button(p, -1,str(elements[0][1]), (10,20))                              
               btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, btn)
               gs.Add(btn, -1, wx.EXPAND)   

    self.btn=wx.Button(p,-1,"Search!")
    bs.Add(self.btn,0,wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

def OnClick(self, event):                                      
    name = event.GetEventObject().GetLabelText()
    cursor= self.conn.execute("SELECT * FROM ELEMENT where SYMBOL==?", (name,))
    elements = cursor.fetchall()
    print elements
    cursor= self.conn.execute("SELECT ATOMIC_NUMBER FROM ELEMENT where SYMBOL = ?", (name,))
    numbers = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    print numbers
    atomicnumber = numbers
    cursor= self.conn.execute("SELECT MOL_NUMBER FROM LINK where ELEMENT_NUMBER = ?", (atomicnumber,))
    mnumbers = cursor.fetchall()
    print mnumbers        
    mnum_list = []
    for i in mnumbers:
         mnum_list.append(i[0])
    print mnum_list
    combinations = atomicnumber
    inter_list = []
    inter_list.append(mnum_list)
    print inter_list
    #print list(set.intersection(*map(set,inter_list))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple lists as follows,

l1 = [1, 6, 7, 8]

l2= [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]

.

.

ln = [2, 4, 7, 8]

```
mylist = []
result = l1
for i in range(1,n):
   mylist.append(locals()['l{}'.format(i)]) 
for s in mylist:
   result = result.intersection(s)
print result
```

This would first join all the lists and then find the intersection between them.

Comment: How do you know the value of n, Are you going to ask user for that?

Comment: And also  global name 'l1' is not defined.

Comment: You have mentioned l1 in your question. And yes the number of buttons to be selected is n.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this if order doesn't matter to you.

```
l1 =[1, 6, 7, 8]
l2= [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]

l3= [2, 4, 7, 8]
inter = list(set(l1)&set(l2)&set(l3))
print(inter)
```

output:

```
[8, 7]
```

**EDIT:** As OP wanted if you say there are going to be a `n` number of list. Get them and store them in a list of list.

```
l1 =[1, 6, 7, 8]
l2= [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
l4= [6,3,7,8]
l5= [1,7,8]
l3= [2, 4, 7, 8]
listoflist = [l1,l2,l3,l4,l5]
a = listoflist[0]  #Assign the first element of listoflist to `a`

for l in listoflist:
    a=set(a)&set(l)

inter = list(a)
print(inter)
```

output:

```
[8, 7]
```

Comment: Can you show me the code , if user has selected n number of buttons, yes i am going to ask user how many buttons you are going to select

Comment: You have created listoflist, How to do that? to do this first i am creating an empty list and then i will append i[0] to it

Comment: `mnumbers` depends on what this is! So if i[0] gives a list. Then just use `your_list.append(i[0])` would do good.

Comment: @TsVilasini Seems like you are wondering how to join multiple lists. Or should i say `append` because you need a list of lists. It's simple if your input from user is a `list` then just append them to a new empty `list`. Use `for` to iterate to `append` several lists.

Comment: i was doing this same thing , you see what i want to do https://pastebin.com/LiJNhgHH

Comment: Yeah i saw what you want to do. But what is your problem exactly?

Comment: I can understand what your problem is but what is happening as to what errors are you getting or what is the problem implementing it?

Comment: Okay you see this , i am sure yiu will get idea what i want https://pastebin.com/LiJNhgHH

Comment: To understand my code see this https://github.com/svnitHIMANSHU/Raman-spectroscopy-database/blob/master/RAMAN.py#L73

Comment: Ok i'll look into it and give a complete solultion when I'm free

Comment: chill it'll be simple. IT'S ALWAYS SIMPLE ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646408/how-to-append-multiple-click-events-and-get-their-intersection

Comment: Got the solution? To your question?

Comment: yup! I will answer it

Answer (score 0):

Here we have to create inter_list outside the On Click event. In this way:

```
             self.inter_list = list()  

def OnClick(self, event):                                       
    name = event.GetEventObject().GetLabelText()
    cursor= self.conn.execute("SELECT * FROM ELEMENT where SYMBOL==?", (name,))
    elements = cursor.fetchall()
    print elements
    cursor= self.conn.execute("SELECT ATOMIC_NUMBER FROM ELEMENT where SYMBOL = ?", (name,))
    numbers = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    atomicnumber = numbers
    cursor= self.conn.execute("SELECT MOL_NUMBER FROM LINK where ELEMENT_NUMBER = ?", (atomicnumber,))
    mnumbers = cursor.fetchall()
    print mnumbers
    mnum_list = []
    for i in mnumbers:
         mnum_list.append(i[0])
    print mnum_list
    self.inter_list.append(mnum_list)
    print self.inter_list
    self.molecule_list=list(set.intersection(*map(set,self.inter_list)))
    print self.molecule_list
    self.t1.AppendText(str(elements[0][0]))
    self.t1.AppendText("\n")
```